# Adding formatter for field in table using CAP CDS annotation

Tags: sap-fiori, cds, sap-cap

[image: table img]

How to remove the decimal points for a field using CAP CDS annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Scale` annotation as it takes integer value that specifies the number of decimal places to display for a field.

For your use case, set the @Scale value to 0.